# Looking for an Android solution to stop the clicking of a tab from changing to the new page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have five pages in my application and if `App.quizRunning == true` and the current page is `Japanese.PhrasesFrame` I need to be able to stop the action of tapping on any of the tabs from doing anything:

```
namespace Japanese {
    public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage {
        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
                App.cardsPage = new Cards();
                App.homePage = new HomePage();
                App.helpPage = new HelpPage();
                App.settingsPage = new SettingsPage();
                App.phrasesPage = new PhrasesFrame(this);
                Children.Add(App.navHomePage);
                Children.Add(App.navHelpPage);
                Children.Add(App.navSettingsPage);
                Children.Add(App.navCardsPage);
                Children.Add(App.navPhrasesFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

So far I have an iOS Solution that I came up with. If anyone sees anything wrong with this I would appreciate there advice:

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Japanese.Enums;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(Japanese.iOS.TabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace Japanese.iOS {
    public class TabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer {

        private MainPage _page;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null) { _page = (MainPage)e.NewElement; }
            else { _page = (MainPage)e.OldElement; }

            try {
                var tabbarController = (UITabBarController)this.ViewController;

                if (null != tabbarController) 
                    tabbarController.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;

            }
            catch (Exception exception) { Console.WriteLine(exception); }
        }

        private void OnTabbarControllerItemSelected(object sender, UITabBarSelectionEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (!(_page.CurrentPage is Japanese.PhrasesFrame) && App.quizRunning == true) {
                _page.CurrentPage = App.navPhrasesFrame;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Now I am looking for an Android solution but have been unable to find anything at all.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this with an Android renderer?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you didn't try `CurrentPage = App.phrasesPage;`

```
override protected void OnCurrentPageChanged() {
            var a = this.CurrentPage;
            if (Settings.mode == MO.Quiz && CurrentPage != App.phrasesPage) {
                // give the user a confirmation/alert box and
                // depending on the outcome set the variable
                // App.continueQuiz to be true or false and then 
                // go back to Japanese.PhrasesFrame page
                CurrentPage = App.phrasesPage;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried that but it only works for one click and the second click takes it away from the phrasesPage.  I tried with a renderer and that works for iOS but not for Android.  Will need to change the question slightly to document what I found has worked so far.

Comment: That means that the second click doesn't fire the OnCurrentPageChanged() event. You're doing ok with renderer, but avoid using logic inside, just send an event to shared code upon tabbar tab selection, where you would process it. Will investigate more when i have time.

Comment: A small clue, what i do in the renderer, i am sending a message to shared code from renderer on every tab selection. Then i can do whatever i want in the shared code that subscribed to this message.